# JPA repository table is not saving new id's but overriding or modifing

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have **A.class**:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class A {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    Integer id;

    String someStringInAclass;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<SomeObject> someObjectsList;
}
```

I have **SomeObject.class**:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class SomeObject {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    Integer id;
    String someString;
    Integer someInteger;
}
```

I save A object in database:

```
SomeRepository.save(A);
```

And tables look like this:

[image]

Then I save A object again with different values in B object:

```
SomeRepository.save(A);
```

Then tables look like this:

[image]

Table B has extended correctly, but table A_B just overrode the B_id instead putting the new one 4 rows.

Then when I retrieve the object A from database I obtain only last 4 values from B object.

How to make it work with saving new values (adding new rows to A_B) without overriding?

**EDIT:**

I added A_id as a foreign key to B table. Again - first save is stored properly:

[image]

Then after second save with different values for B, it modifies values for A_id column for firstable inserted 4 values (to null). So the table looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want a different table for oneToMany relationship ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use JPA.

Comment: @Tarun I don't know what you mean. Is there any other way I will be able to do this?

Comment: I mean, If this is one-to-many relationship, You could save id of A in B table as foreign key instead of having a different table A_B.

Comment: @Tarun I added A_id as a foreign key to B table. First save is stored properly, but with second save I obtain: null values for A_id column?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate handle unidirectional relationships very inefficiently please try to use bidirectional relationship.

Regarding above issue, you don't need third table here, you can avoid creation of third table by adding @JoinColumn as below :

```
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)   
     @JoinColumn(name = "fk_a_id")
     List<SomeObject> someObjectsList;
```

this will add column "fk_a_id" in SOME_OBJECT table.

Comment: I added: (nullable = false) parameter for @JoinColumn the problem is solved. Name is not needed.

Comment: Yes that constraint is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the object is already saved and has an assigned id, JPA assumes you mean the same entry in the database. You need to clone the object:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class A {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    Integer id;

    String someStringInAclass;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<SomeObject> someObjectsList;

    public A(A source) {
        this.someStringInAclass = source.someStringInAClass;
        this.someObjectsList = new ArrayList<SomeObject>();

        for (SomeObject o : source.someObjectsList) {
            this.someObjectsList.add(new SomeObject(o));
        }
    }
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
SomeRepository.save(a);
A aClone = new A(a);
SomeRepository.save(aClone);
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure but this will extend A table with new objects?

Comment: No. It is just a copy constructor. Since the class is already "registered" with the JPA implementation, you need a new instance. I extended the example to include the cloning of the SomeObject-Instances as well.

Answer (score 0):

I added: `(nullable = false)` parameter for `@JoinColumn` the problem is solved.

So above the list there is now:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
List<SomeObject> someObjectsList;
```